# @import file.scss string in scssphp

Tags: php, sass

I'm using scssphp to convert my SCSS files directly to CSS file via PHP.

But now I have a problem making this work. The documentation is a bit lacking in my opinion, because I can't seem to figure it out. I have an `index.php` file and a `createsass.php` file.

**index.php:**

```
<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die; 
require 'css/createsass.php';
include_once JPATH_THEMES.'/'.$this->template.'/logic.php';
```

**In the PHP logic I add the `createsass.php`:**

```
$doc->addStyleSheet($tpath.'/css/createsass.php');
```

**createsass.php:**

```
require "scss.inc.php";
$scss = new scssc();
echo $scss->compile('@import "template.scss"');
```

But now I have a very weird rendered page with the `<head>` in the body, and the text "@import template.scss" above in my content. How the hell do you make this work?

[image: weird text above content and head content in body]

Comment: Is there anything in your error logs that raises your eyebrow during this process?

Comment: Are you using a different fork or version than the one described [in this documentation](http://leafo.github.io/scssphp/docs/)?

Comment: I used the latest version on the website, used the button on the page you provided. There aren't any error logs available. Although I have a feeling that I'm doing something wrong. Because the require isn't described anywhere, but I still need it to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible whatever templating you're using is some of the issue. First thing to check is the output of hitting the php file directly. If that's not giving you the correct output then I think this is likely to be one of two issues:

1. Your file is not found in the include path. From the docs:

> When you import a file using the @import directive, the current path of your PHP script is used as the search path by default. This is often not what you want, so there are two methods for manipulating the import path: `addImportPath`, and `setImportPaths`.

see here: http://leafo.net/scssphp/docs/#import_paths

2. Your file is named incorrectly. `@import('template.scss')` would expect to import a file called `_template.scss`

Comment: I'm not using an import path because everything is in the same directory. Changing the name to _template.scss doesn't change a thing.

Comment: What is your templating language? What url are you hitting to access `css/createsass.php` file? What is the output of that?

Comment: I'm using PHP. In the index.php file (root template file) I have 1 line of code to import the php file (located in the css folder) "require 'css/createsass.php';" After that I use the above code to import the scss file. The output of the line of code is this screenshot http://i.imgur.com/naR14u3.png

Comment: Okay, but `"require 'css/createsass.php';"` isn't at the end of your index.php so what is the rest of that file about? `JPATH_THEMES` suggests joomla. I would suggest removing all that from the equation. If you hit eg http://server.address/css/createsass.php then you should get the rendered css (I'm assuming index.php is served from the http root directory here).

Comment: Yes, if I go directly to the file I get the rendered CSS on the page.

Comment: The problem isn't the fact that the rendering doesn't get through, it does. But the problem is the string of text above my content, plus the fact that my head isn't rendered properly anymore, see screenshot.

Comment: I checked and the require is giving me troubles. If I remove that String the import doesn't get through, but if I keep it it gives that weird string...

Comment: Okay, but from my undersanding it shouldn't be included in your index. The `createsass.php` should be linked to in the template with your `addStyleSheet` call so should not be in `index.php` at all. Can you try the `addStyleSheet` call without the `$tpath` prefix?

Comment: Yeah it shouldn't be. It's not described anywhere, but the problem is it only works with that require/include. If I remove the include and add the stylesheet only it won't work. I get this in console: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "/css/createsass.php".

Comment: I can award you the bounty if you have another way of using SASS without the need to overwrite the used CSS on my server constantly. I guess working with scssphp will not work

Comment: The way the path is specified is actually valid SASS, see http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `scssc` class in the codebase (0.6.6) or documentation of scssphp. 
According to the documentation you should use the `Compiler` class.

```
use Leafo\ScssPhp\Compiler;

$scss = new Compiler();
```

Comment: This gives me a white page. If you check this example, http://leafo.net/scssphp/ , it's just like I had it, but that gives me that weird string of text. Weird that nobody else has this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> scssphp comes with a easy to use class that automatically compiles modified scss files and serves them from a directory you specify.

http://leafo.github.io/scssphp/

Move your `createsass.php` file into the root directory, then change the contents to match what is given on the scssphp website.

```
<?php
require "path/to/scssphp/scss.inc.php";

use Leafo\ScssPhp\Server;

$directory = "css";

Server::serveFrom($directory);
```

Make sure `template.scss` (and not `_template.css`) is in your `css` directory. Then update your code to add the css as: `http://example.com/createsass.php/style.scss` (though you may want to rename createsass.php to something else).

One other thing to note:

> scssphp will automatically create a scss_cache directory inside the stylesheets directory where it will cache the compiled output. This way it can quickly serve the files if no modifications have been made. Your PHP script must have permission to write in scss_cache.